# Is there a way to update an email thread in Gmail with the keyboard?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

I find it frustrating that Gmail uses an ajax or other system to put a yellow box in the bottom right of an email thread to tell you that you got a new email, but it doesn't just go put the actual email there for you to read it.

I'm hoping there's at least a keyboard shortcut that I can use to tell it to load it (same as if I clicked the "show" link in the yellow box).

I think it's probably possible to write a tampermonkey script to do this, but I don't know how to do that yet.

Maybe an extension exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut would be to use: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

> Update current conversation - Updates your current conversation when there are new messages.

[It's not one of the defaults](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en), you'll have to make sure you have "Keyboard shortcuts on" setting.

Comment: Tested and working. I would love it if this could be done automatically instead of manually, but at least this shortcut allows me to stay on the keyboard.